# Permission denied on all hard drives after reinstalling windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, file-permissions

I've just reinstalled windows 10 and it's created a new user/ID. Now all my hard drives are read-only because the new user doesn't match the old one (what a wonderful system to have). I still access everything from windows explorer but keep getting asked for admin privileges. The problem is any apps, that try to save things fail. Luckily steam seems to know how to fix this when I first ran it (kudos to them for going out of their way to fix something windows isn't prepared for), although it took a while.

[image]

I believe the normal fix is to keep messing round with folder properties and the security tab, waiting a while for windows to individually change permissions while recursing into every single directory on the entire disk. Not to mention getting errors when it hits system files like the recycle bin.

The `takeown` command looked promising and takes ages, but I still get the same access denied.

```
takeown /F Z: /R /D Y
```

Is there a clean, painless solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just do 
icacls PATH /reset /t /q

where PATH is the folder/drive that is giving you trouble
and you'll be good to go. It will reset permissions to default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick: quick share a folder of the drive to your own user, that could bypass the issue.

If it does not, you will have to take the good old 're-assimilate them all' approach:

- Click on properties of the drive and go to “Security” tab.
- Click on “Advanced” and in Advanced Security Dialog window, click on “Owner” tab.
- Check the current owner. To take ownership, click on the Edit button.Then highlight your user name in the “Change owner to” box and click “OK” to finish the process.
- Back in Advanced Security Settings window, you will see the current owner has changed to your user. Click “OK” button to exit this window. Click “OK” again to exit completely from the Properties window.
- Go to the object’s Properties window again.
- In object’s Properties window, click on Edit button, and confirm to UAC if needed.
- Highlight the Administrators in the “Group or user names” box. If the user ID or group that you want to manage the permissions for the object does not exist, click on “Add” button, and type in the user name or group name desired into the “Enter object names to select [...]” box, and then “OK”.
- In the Permissions for Administrators box below (or any other user name or group name you chose), click on “Full Control” under the “Allow” column to assign full access rights control permissions to Administrators group.

If that also somehow fails, you will have to enable the default administrator account and try the same procedure from that one (elevated cmd --> `net user administrator /active:yes`).

Another way is to try using subinacl. Download the official subinacl.msi and install it.

Then, open an elevated cmd and paste the following lines:

```
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE /grant=administrators=f
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CURRENT_USER /grant=administrators=f
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT /grant=administrators=f
subinacl /subdirectories %SystemDrive% /grant=administrators=f
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE /grant=system=f
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CURRENT_USER /grant=system=f
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT /grant=system=f
subinacl /subdirectories %SystemDrive% /grant=system=f
```

What this does is fix the user account rights.